# Appcelerator facebook login button events not working with alloy

Tags: ios, facebook, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using the alloy framework with appcelerator titanium and have done like this:

alloy.js

```
Alloy.Globals.Facebook = require('facebook');
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.permissions = ['public_profile'];
```

index.js

```
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        Ti.API.info("VALID FACEBOOK LOGIN");

        var token = Alloy.Globals.Facebook.accessToken;
        Ti.API.info("*** fb accessToken: "+token);

    }
    else{
        Ti.API.info("FAILED FACEBOOK LOGIN...");
    }
});
```

index.xml

```
<LoginButton id="fbButton" module="facebook" />
```

When i try to login using the button, the login is okay, and the facebook button changes to "logout" instead. However, no login event is ever fired and the evenlistener in index.js never gets anything.

What is causing this? Should i add the event lister in some other way?

iOS on device 9.3.1
Titanium SDK 5.2.2.GA

Comment: possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502862/appcelerator-facebook-module-doesnt-fire-login-event/36506046#36506046

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is for iOS, they are talking about Android and the solution proposed there are for android.

Comment: ok dupplicated in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627325/fb-authorize-never-give-a-login-event/36628987#36628987

Comment: In your code never initialize the module

Comment: No Jagu, still not a duplicate. That questions is using the fb.authorize(). This questions is using Alloy framework and the facebook LoginButton which does not use the fb.authorize().   :)     (Will try add the .initialize() thing into my code in alloy.js though and see if that works...)

Comment: Ok, sorry :D you can share the plist?

Comment: Actually, adding initialize() in alloy.js seems to help...     
    Alloy.Globals.Facebook = require('facebook');
    Alloy.Globals.Facebook.permissions = ['public_profile'];
    Alloy.Globals.Facebook.initialize();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in an earlier comment to the question the module was not initialized. Adding the initialize() line into my alloy.js seems to fix the problem, now i receive the login events.

in alloy.js

```
Alloy.Globals.Facebook = require('facebook');
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.permissions = ['public_profile'];
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget to add this instruction :

```
Alloy.Globals.Facebook.authorize();
```

Comment: It should not be necessary when using the alloy LoginButton... At least thats what I understand from the documentation? The facebook LoginButton should handle that by itself.

Answer (score 0):

As an ugly workaround until events gets fixed i simply added a setInterval that polls if Alloy.Globals.Facebook.loggedIn is true or not and then do the appropriate codes that should have been inside the event handler...

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the app to app store, for some reason the reviewers could not get any events... this is really bad. It works in my simulators and on my device, but not for the submitted app when they test it...

No idea what to do really...